# Ubuntu MS SQL Server RESTORE fails beacuse 'LOG_BACKUP' is full

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I have a MS SQL SERVER 2008 backup (all files .bak). I have a computer with Ubuntu and I want to restore the backup.

First I installed the SQL Server on Ubuntu with this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ubuntu)

Then I installed DBeaver

Now I am trying to restore the databases with this command

```
RESTORE DATABASE dfy2_alquiler
FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/dfy2_alquiler.bak'
WITH MOVE 'dfy2_alquiler_Data' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/dfy2_alquiler_Data.mdf',
MOVE 'dfy2_alquiler_Log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/dfy2_alquiler_Log.ldf';
```

But I am getting this error

> SQL Error [9002] [S0002]: The transaction log for database 'dfy2_alquiler' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'.
>     com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The transaction log for database 'dfy2_alquiler' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'.

I am not sure how can I solve this?

Comment: If the system that you took the backups from is still online, can you verify that the log file for this database is not set to have a limited maximum size and that autogrow is enabled for it?

Comment: If the db is still available... id be tempted to import via ssis. Restoring from win to linux sounds unpleasant.

Comment: ìt sounds to me like you are running out of disk space for the ldf file. If you run a RESTORE FILELISTONLY then you can see the disk space requirements. The ldf file may be much bigger than both your bak file and the mdf file.

Comment: @SeanGallardy thank you for your answer, I will try to check for that.

Comment: @Peter I am trying to test the backup before it is needed, I will try to do it on another windows. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @HenrikStaunPoulsen I thought that, but I am only using the 10% on the disk I was trying to do the RESTORE, maybe there is another constrain in the config files. Thank you for your answer/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the transaction log needs to grow during the upgrade portion of the restore from 2008 to vNext, but is unable to. Here are a few things to try:

- Back up the log on the source database
- Enable autogrowth on the source database log, if not already enabled
- Make sure the autogrowth amount is set to a size that is smaller than the amount of free space on the target volume
- Size the log on the source database so that it has some free space and won't have to autogrow during the restore
- Take a fresh full backup and retry the restore to the target linux instance